# Have an error when using lambda in python, do you know why?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I was trying to have a checkbox which switches the value of a variable when clicked on(w/tkinter):

```
import tkinter as tk

CheckVar1 = tk.IntVar()
    isOn = False
    C1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text = "Decreasing", variable = CheckVar1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=5)
    C1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3)
    C1.bind("<<CheckboxSelect>>",lambda _: isOn = True if isOn == False else False)
    print(isOn)
```

But I'm having trouble with lambda:

```
lambda _: isOn = True if isOn == False else False
```

It gives an error, do you know why? How can I fix it?

Comment: You cannot assign inside of `lambda`. Make a function instead.

Comment: didn't know that, thanks a lot

Comment: `isOn` is not necessary.  Use `CheckVar1` to get the current state of the checkbutton.

Comment: It worked, thanks. But I don't have to use my own variable at all. I can use CheckVar1 to make it work. Still I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lambda`s are not supposed to have assignments, it just used for expressions and calling other functions. But there is a hacky way to assign inside of `lambda`. But first the correct way:

```
def check():
    global isOn
    if not isOn:   
        isON = True
    else:
        isOn = False
```

So the hacky way includes using `exec` to execute python code inside of `lambda`, like:

```
C1.bind("<<CheckboxSelect>>",lambda _: exec('isOn=not isOn',globals())) # Thanks to Dr. Casual for the idea
# Also recommended to use event or e or something else instead of _
```

So you could just change your entire `check()` to:

```
def check():
    global isOn
    isOn = not isOn
```

Comment: for short and readable code, do `isOn = not isOn` :)